# Taking input for HOST/PORT else connect with default HOST/PORT

Tags: python

I'm trying to have query() ask for a hostname and port, try and if unsuccessful just attempt connecting to the default host/port(localhost/21567).

```
from socket import *
import re

HOST = 'localhost'  # server IP
PORT = 21567        # port
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
ip = re.compile(r'([0-9\.]{1,3}){4}')

def query():
    while True:
    hostc = raw_input('Host: ')
    portc = int(input('Port: '))
    if (portc != None & bool(re.match(ip, hostc))):
        try:
            tcpCliSock.connect(hostc, portc)
            break
        except:
            pass
        print("\nInvalid Entry.\n")
    else:
        tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)
        break

tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)   # allocate client's socket
query()
```

Here's what I get when I don't input anything at all:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tcpclient.py", line 30, in <module>
    query()
  File "./tcpclient.py", line 17, in query
    portc = int(input('Port: '))
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

And if I enter a valid host/port(there's a server waiting at this addr):

```
Host: 192.168.1.103
Port: 21567

Invalid Entry.

Host:
```

I'm trying to make it so if no values are entered it goes to the outer else to connect to the default HOST/PORT, otherwise if values entered are valid it connects to hostc/portc.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Sphere that the code snippet your question is not exactly pythonic and there is definitely a better way to do what you want to accomplish. However, having said that, just taking your code snippet - I have modified it to work as far as establishing a socket connection goes. Let me know how it goes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from socket import *
#import re

HOST = 'localhost'  # server IP
PORT = 21567        # port
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
#ip = re.compile(r'([0-9\.]{1,3}){4}')


def validate_ip(ip):
    try:
        if inet_aton(ip):
           return True
    except:
        return False

def query():
    while True:
        hostc = raw_input('Host: ')
        portc = raw_input('Port: ')
        if (portc and validate_ip(hostc)):
            try:
                tcpCliSock.connect(hostc, int(portc))
                break
            except:
                pass
            #print("\nInvalid Entry.\n")
        else:
            tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)
            break

tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)   # allocate client's socket
query()
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was so, I'll try rewriting it so it takes arguments instead of asking during runtime. This worked for me, thank you for hacking my sh*tty code.

Comment: no worries - we are all here to learn to be better everyday. If the code works, would appreciate if you could accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are some not very "pythonic" things in your code, but regarding your question I would do something like:
`hostc = raw_input('Host: ') or HOST`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the better answer to my own question, hopefully more 'pythony', thank you to sphere and ssheth for suggesting it could be done better:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--host", type=str, default='localhost',
                    help="Host other than %(default)s.")
parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=21567, 
                    help="Port other than %(default)s.")
args = parser.parse_args()

HOST = args.host
PORT = args.port
```